# Stream builder is not updating frequently

Tags: flutter

I am trying to stream comments(you can see in the code). but stream builder is not updating, but when I do hot reload then it shows data. I am unable to understand why the stream builder is only showing data after hot reload?

I tried but I am not understanding why such behavior is with a stream builder

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: reference
                  .where("post_id", isEqualTo: widget.postModel.uid)
                  .orderBy("created", descending: true)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                var postList =
                    snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.documents : null;
                print("size: $postList");
                return (snapshot != null &&
                        (!snapshot.hasData || postList.length == 0))
                    ? Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "No comments yet",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: postList.length,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          Map<String, dynamic> dataMap =
                              postList[index].data;
                          return Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.tag_faces,
                                      color: Colors.black45,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 8,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      dataMap["name"],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          color: Colors.black54,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 4,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  dataMap["comment"],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        });
              })
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

> Refactor (simplify) your widget tree.

Sometimes it happens because of widget tree. Try to refactor by analyzing the same screen's widget tree.
It's like your stream builder fails to keep itself updated (i.e. It doesn't continually check data changes in the backend because it lost focus or something which keeps it updated.)